# creating directory from Java on a shared location

Tags: java, runtime, directory, java-io, filewriter

I can't seem to figure out why I can't create a directory from a Java program FOR A SPECIFIC LOCATION.
The specifics are - the folder of my computer is shared on the network.

Code:

```
File xmlDirectory = new File(sXMLOutputPath);

 /*
  * TODO: if multiple threads arive at the 1st if, if will evaluate to true, 
  * then 1st thread would create directory, and the 2nd being .01 sec later, will fail   
  *  to create directory and have exception
  * SOLUTION:  Provide additional if exists, so that 2nd thread will recognize that it 
  *  was created.  
  */
 if (!xmlDirectory.exists()){
     if (!xmlDirectory.mkdirs()){
       if (!xmlDirectory.exists()){
          throw new BillAdminException("Failed to create xml directory: " + 
           sXMLOutputPath);
       }
     }
 }
```

This is a server side code

In summary - if I share my foder C:\folder\etc - and pass it as JVM options to the program, the server side program "appends" \xml\333\333.xml" to it, and is supposed to create that xml file on MY PC. First it creates a structire C:\folder\etc\xml\333\, and then it creates 333.xml.  It fails creating C:\folder\etc\xml\333 if the C:\folder\etc is passed as shared location in the form "\myMachine\etc", but works OK if I make that structure on some other machine "\OtherMachine\etc".  If I pass it as "C:\folder\etc" (absolute, not shared form) it will work fine, creating directory and file on the server machine where code is executed.  I need it created on my machine (client).  What am I doing wrong when sharing folder.
P.S - this functionality worked about 2 month ago.  However, the folder properties could have been tempered with since then.  Not the java code, though.

P.S 2: this is not the only shared folder I pass from JVM options.  There are 2 others, but used for reading (not creating subfolders)
Thanks, for help

P.S 3: The error I get is:

```
Failed to create xml directory: \\myMachine\etc\xml/333/
```

What I smell fishy, is that the slash before "333" is reversed.  But, there were no changes in the code, so the same would have been happening before.

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions?

Comment: If I go to that server manually (with my network login), I can access that my own shared folder, and create directories.  Same for someone else with different login.  Either with windows or with dos mkdir.  So, the question is - does the application or weblogic have permisison?  How to check?